# How to force wireshark to show protocol names?

Tags: windows, networking, filtering, wireshark, network-protocols

[image]

As shown in the screenshot above, the protocol column always shows correct signs rather than the actual protocol name. The wireshark version is 3.6.5.

How to force wireshark to show protocol names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Wireshark main menu -> Edit -> Preferences
2. Appearance -> Columns
3. Go to line having "Protocol" in the "Title" column
4. What is in the "Type" field in the line? If there is anything other than "Protocol", click and select "Protocol" in the list.

[image]